# Расширение в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, расширения

кто может подсказать, какое расширение добавляет окно на скриншоте и как его выключить?[image: вот этот скрин][image: Расширение вот]

Comment: это подсказки типов которые возвращяет функция. полезная штука

Comment: Так вы сами всё нашли. Только требуется перезагрузка. Нажмите прямо на надпись.